# Finite State Machine

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

My task is to design a FSM whose output goes high for a single cycle whenever the pattern 10110 is detected on its input. I am assuming I will need five state bubbles.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

<s>State 0 is only needed immediately after reset. A 0 in state 2 should go back to state 1, and state 4 should go back to state 1 immediately after emit. Also, you have 2 transitions for state 3 on a' (only the one to state 4 is needed).</s>

A lot harder than I thought it would be. And even this is probably more complex than it needs to be. State 4 indicates a match.

[image: 0(110)+]

Comment: Thank you.  What does the emit mean in state 4?  Would that be a'?

Comment: That would be emitting 1 on the output.

Comment: Ah, alright.  So what input would I have on state 4 going to state 1?  Or would I just draw an arrow?

Comment: There wouldn't be an input for it; it would be an automatic transition. We need to separate out state 4 explicitly since we can't have an emit on every entry to state 1 (e.g. 0 -> 0).

Comment: That will fail to match 0110110.

Comment: Alright so remove the a' and a coming from state 4 and just put an arrow going to state 1?  Because I can't write emit on the transition lines, only a or a'.

Comment: That is correct. We use the 0 we received before going into 4 as part of the next sequence, but only if a 1 is received after.

Comment: Correct. It's used to catch runs of 1s greater than 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
       |    1         0
-----------------------
INITIAL|    1   INITIAL 
     1 |    1        10
    10 |  101   INITIAL
   101 | 1011        10
  1011 |    1     10110
 10110 |    -         -
```

I cant post pictures, so I chose to fall back to 'table' version of the FSM (if you reconstruct the picture from it, everything would be clear).

Left-most column in the table represents possible states (6 in total - *INITIAL,1,10,101,1011,10110*), top row  represents possible inputs (`0` and `1`). Content of the table represents transition from one state (left column) to another state under given input (top row).

explained:
You start and wait in *INITIAL* state reading any `0`s that come in.

When you hit `1`, you transit to state *1* then you continue from there in similar fashion ... Basically the names of the states represent the longest "good" read part of the input, but this is only for better orientation, you could name the states whatever you want. State *10110* is final. If you reach it, you should fire the signal or whatever.

Here is a catch in your question, though: you havent specified if you just want to fire the signal every time the last 5 digits are `10110`, or if you want to 'reset the counter' after you find that sequence.

Therefore you can add transition from state *10110* to *101* under `1` and to *INITIAL* state under `0`, if you want to fire a signal every time "the last 5 digits on input were `10110`".

Otherwise add transition from state *10110* to *INITIAL* state under both `0` and `1` (that means "forget everything you read so far and start again").

Answer (score -1):

Although Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer is close, it fails if 0110 is input from start.

[image: State Machine]

Comment: This will not accept 110110